# What happens when my method takes too long to complete when using a timer in obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have a method in my iPhone project that is called upon by an NSTimer every 0.05 seconds. I created the timer using:

```
NSTimer myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self 
     selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The method is set up like most. Here is its outline:

```
-(void)myMethod {
     //Lots of processing
}
```

Now here's the issue. It is quite possible that the method's execution time will be greater than 0.05 seconds (the interval for calling the method). What will happen if the execution of the method is equal to or greater than that of the interval 0.05? Will a second CPU thread be opened, or could the program crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, I advise you to do the test.

I have created a simple one view iOS app, and changed toe viewController class to the following:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Test
//

#import "ViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()

@property NSTimer *myTimer;

@end



@implementation ViewController


- (void) myMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Entered TestClass");

    sleep(3);

    NSLog(@"Exited TestClass");
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(myMethod)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:YES];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.myTimer invalidate];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


@end
```

The console listing of this test shows us:

```
2014-06-19 08:30:56.628 Test[589:60b] Entered TestClass
2014-06-19 08:30:59.632 Test[589:60b] Exited TestClass
2014-06-19 08:31:00.627 Test[589:60b] Entered TestClass
2014-06-19 08:31:03.628 Test[589:60b] Exited TestClass
2014-06-19 08:31:04.627 Test[589:60b] Entered TestClass
2014-06-19 08:31:07.628 Test[589:60b] Exited TestClass
2014-06-19 08:31:08.627 Test[589:60b] Entered TestClass
2014-06-19 08:31:11.628 Test[589:60b] Exited TestClass
```

Conclusion: since you are not launching your myMethod in a parallel asynchronous thread, your routine only starts after the previous run has been terminated. And the timer even takes it's time (in this case 1 second) to relaunch your myMethod.

Happy programming !

Answer (score 1):

assuming everything are happening in main thread, this what is going on

- NSRunloop running

  - runloop check timer

    - call `myMethod`

      - do some heavy work
    - after 0.1s, `myMethod` returned
  - runloop do some other work
  - back to beginning

so basically your method is get called every 0.1s (plus time taken to perform addition work) instead of 0.05s

Comment: So assuming the heavy work takes x seconds,                              if x <= .05, the method is called every 0.05 seconds                         but if x > .05, the method is called every x seconds?

Answer (score 0):

It will run your function in main thread . which may halt some other operation.
The best practice for these kind of method is to run them in an background thread.